# Get date from date picker in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have created an `IBOutlet` to a date picker.

`@IBOutlet weak var logDate: UIDatePicker!`

I have also set the `mode` of this date picker to `date`.

Is there a way for me to extract the date that the user would input into the date picker?

I tried using `print(logdate)`, however it also gives me the date along with the time. Like this `2015-10-30 07:10:03 +0000`

Comment: So you would like to get the date as a `String`?

Comment: I would prefer it as a String.

Comment: Lookup NSDateFormatter. There are hundreds of examples on SO. There is also a "Data Formatting Guide" from Apple.

Comment: @MartinR the Data formatting guide is written in Objective C

Comment: Then lookup the methods, the NSDateFormatter (and all other Cocoa) docs show both Objective-C and Swift

Comment: @Sachin logDate.date will return the selected date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the date inputted by the user in a date field using this code. 
Note: This solution extracts the input as a string

```
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle   // You can also use Long, Medium and No style.
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle   

    var inputDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(*datepicker outlet name*.date)
    print(inputDate)
```

Used a section of code from: http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/display-date-date-picker-ios8-swift

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you want this:

```
let components = logDate.calendar.components([.Era, .Year, .Month, .Day],
    fromDate: logDate.date)
print("\(components.era) \(components.year) \(components.month) \(components.day)")

// Output: 1 2015 10 31
```

Or perhaps you want this:

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.calendar = logDate.calendar
formatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
formatter.timeStyle = .NoStyle
let dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(logDate.date)
print(dateString)

// Output: Oct 31, 2015
```

You can try another `dateStyle` setting, or be more explicit by setting the `dateFormat` property. [The `dateFormat` syntax can get pretty hairy.](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) Remember to use `yyyy`, **not** `YYYY`, for the year part of your format. But it's `MM`, **not** `mm` for the month part. Example:

```
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
print(formatter.stringFromDate(logDate.date))

// Output: 2015-10-31
```

Answer (score 2):

Get hour and minute in swift 5

```
let comp = datePickerOutlet.calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: datePickerOutlet.date)

print(comp.hour!)
print(comp.minute!)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

It's more simple than it appears. Just create a var of type Date and set its value from the datePicker outlet like this.

```
@IBOutlet weak var yourDatePicker: NSDatePicker!

var date = Date()

@IBAction func datePickerChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    date = yourDatePicker.dateValue
}
```

Now you can use that variable to insert date values on Core Data's attributes of type Date or something like that.

Comment: This would be ideal, except when you drag a datePicker from object library onto your ViewController, you get a UIDatePicker outlet, NOT a NSDatePicker object.  Thus "dateValue" doesn't work.  This solution is going to confuse people who don't notice you've used NSDatePicker.

Answer (score 0):

Create an action from your datePicker

```
  @IBAction func calenderSelection(_ sender: Any) {
        let date = datePicker.date // Get your selected date 
        print(date)
    }
```